# How to get who and when a user shared a Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, share

For my Facebook posts my friends share (not likes) I would like get who shared it and when. Using the graph api I can get the like or comment information and the number of times a post has been shared.
What I am looking for is a graph api call or Facebook fql query for shares which returns a result set similar to this:

```
data": [
      {
         "id": "user_id_1",
         "name": "Username 1",
         "created": "some date"
      },
      {
         "id": "user_id_2",
         "name": "Username 2",
         "created": "some other date"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748037/list-of-people-who-shared-on-facebook#comment24076740_7748252

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for the exact thing for long time now. Since Facebook shows the list of users who shared the post, I was expecting that the same will be available in Graph API. But unfortunately nothing such exists till date.

The best workaround I could find for this problem is [scraping](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8675389/375233) the Facebook page for the list of users who shared the given post. I haven't yet tried this solution but this should solve the problem for now. The only issue here is, if Facebook changes the HTML structure of that page, the **scraper** will have to modified.