# How to get user id who shared my post (in page)

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-fql, userid

With fql, i'd like to get user id who shared my post.
Which table can i retrieve that info. 
i checked out comment, like, and link table
but could'nt find any word regarding 'share'

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21050608/496538