# Getting User IDs of people that share a post on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This question was partially answered here:

[List of people who shared on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748037/list-of-people-who-shared-on-facebook/7748252#7748252)

You can make the following call and get some data back as described in the answer with this link:

https://www.facebook.com/ajax/shares/view/?target_fbid=10151733211231729&__a=1

however, this just returns the initial batch of IDs. The post here:

https://www.facebook.com/10151733211231729

Has over 10,400 shares, and the call above only returns the first 42 IDs. So does anyone know how to harvest via pagination or how to extract the "next" link from the data we get back? UIDs of people that share a post isn't available anywhere in the Graph API, so parsing this call is crucial.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post some of your code? What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Right now I have no code for scraping shares and there is no published API call for getting the shares.