# How to get photo share detailed data using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As a matter of fact, I wanna have detailed list of how the stuff are shared on Facebook. I mean, you can browse a list of people who publicly shared a post or photo of a fan page, and know **who** has shared it and **when**, and how many **likes** and **comments** it received after sharing, and read the text attached to the shared item.

For example, [this](https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=974603969217718) is a sample of these detailed data.

Although there are easy ways to extract comments and likes of a specific post, I could not find any practicable ways to retrieve these sorts of share data using the API. The only way (which is much dirty) is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748037/list-of-people-who-shared-on-facebook#comment24076740_7748252).

Note that the simple number of shares is not sufficient, there are much more data needed.

By the way, I'm a newbie dealing with Facebook Graph API, hence, I would appreciate if you give the http GET commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am pretty sure those things are not available with the graph api, and since scraping is not allowed you are not allowed to grab it directly from that link.

Comment: Thanks @luschn. But you know, almost all other things are reachable through the graph api.

Comment: that´s not true. a LOT of things are not available with the graph api. even if they are public. main principle: without user authorization, you should not get anything from any user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid @luschn is right. You cannot do any thing with graph api. I guess the page you found is the only way.